# What does * and ** mean in a C++ function declaration?

Tags: c++

In this function declaration:

```
long * multiply(long ** numbers){
```

What do the * and ** mean? I'm somewhat of a beginner and haven't come across this before, so any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: They're pointers and pointers to pointers.

Comment: They are [pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer). They are a very basic and fundamental type. However you are learning c++, through a book, a class or whatever else you might be using, they will eventually cover it.

Answer (score 2):

[Pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer):

> **Pointer declarator:**  the declaration S* D; declares D as a pointer to the type determined
>   by decl-specifier-seq S.

Further:

> A pointer that points to an object represents the address of the first byte in memory occupied by the object.

`long*` is a pointer to `long`. `long**` is a pointer to `long*`.

[There is more you should read about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and better stay away for some time from code that has a function declaration like this:

```
long * multiply(long ** numbers)
```

It is hard to think of a realistic scenario where multiplying numbers requires you to use a `long**`. Raw pointers are easy to use wrong and in modern C++ you rather only use them when you need to (which is actually quite rare).